# Как получть деньги с продажи приложения в Google Play?

Tags: google-play, платежи

Хочу сделать платное приложение для Google Play, меня интересует следующий момент. Куда будут начисляться деньги с продажи и как их вывести в реал? Надо ли зводить специальную карточку для начисления денежных средств на нее? Какую комисию берет Google с продажи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Деньги начисляются прямо в Google Play. Там же выбираете куда вам скидывать деньги. Лучший вариант для вас банковской картой. Оформляете карту для международных платежей. Прям идете в банк и говорите: "Дайте мне карту для международных платежей". Карту мне сделали за 10 минут. В Сбербанке бесплатная вроде была, в долларах и евро. Google забирает 30%, но он все время пишет примерно. Т.е. вот моя последняя на данный момент покупка сделана на 50 рублей, комиссия по словам google: "Примерно 15,00 руб".

Comment: Я понял что у Вас уже есть успешные приложения которые продаются. Можете подсказать в какой ценовой категории лучше выкладывать приложение?

Comment: Все зависит от приложения. Тут так сразу не скажешь. И вообще, если у вас не мега оригинальное приложение, советую вам сделать игру бесплатной, но с внутренними покупками и рекламой. Больше выручите. Т.к. в основном успешные, платные игры делают компании с группой программистов. Но бывают и исключения.

Comment: А что если сделать бесплатную версию с рекламой и платную без, это будет приносить прибыль?

Comment: Да, почему нет. Просто нужно четко определить, чем платная лучше бесплатной. Донести это до пользователя. Бесплатная будет что-то подобии демо версии. Если пользователю понравиться, он  купит полную.